# How can I upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8 without affecting Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my PC. I want to remove Windows 7 and install Windows 8, without removing Ubuntu. I know that a fresh install of Windows usually completely removes any other operating systems. Is there any way to upgrade to Windows 8 without interfering with my installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: "Is there any way to upgrade to Windows 8 without interfering with my installation of Ubuntu?" You probably need to ask this to a Microsoft employee. IF(!) something affects your system it will be due to Windows but we know nothing about the internal working of windows. We do know UEFI is a nightmare but if it is goign to be a problem... not for us to say ;) Besides that: of course you make a backup of your files.